# Data selection using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a file where the separator(delimiter) is ';' . I read that file into a pandas dataframe **df**. Now, I want to select some rows from df using a criteria from **column c** in **df**. The format of data in column c is as follows:

```
[0]science|time|boot
[1]history|abc|red
and so on...
```

I have another list of words **L**, which has values such as

```
[history, geography,....]
```

Now, if I split the text in column c on '|', then I want to select those rows from df, where the first word does not belong to L.

Therefore, in this example, I will select df[0] but will not chose df[1], since history is present in L and science is not.

I know, I can write a for loop and iter over each object in the dataframe but I was wondering if I could do something in a more compact and efficient way.

For example, we can do:

```
df.loc[df['column_name'].isin(some_values)]
```

I have this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';', header=None, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)
dat=df.ix[:,c].str.split('|')
```

But, I do not know how to index 'dat'. 'dat' is a **Pandas Series**, as follows:

```
 0                     [science, time, boot]
 1                     [history, abc, red]
 ....
```

I tried indexing dat as follows:

```
dat.iloc[:][0]
```

But, it gives the entire series instead of just the first element.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach:

**Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':['history|science','science|chemistry','geography|science','biology|IT'],'col2':range(4)})

Out[433]:
                   c  col2
0    history|science     0
1  science|chemistry     1
2  geography|science     2
3         biology|IT     3

lst = ['geography', 'biology','IT']
```

**Resolution**

You can use list comprehension:

```
df.loc[pd.Series([not x.split('|')[0] in lst for x in df.c.tolist()])]

Out[444]:
                   c  col2
0    history|science     0
1  science|chemistry     1
```